# i am having problem with update my textView in onPostExecute

Tags: android

```
public void connectScaleService() {

      try {
          mScaleManager.getData(new ScaleCallback.Stub() {
              @Override
              public void getData(final int i, int i1, final int i2) throws RemoteException {

           
                  new SetValues(i2,i).execute();

              }
          });
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          Log.e("check exception", e.getMessage());
      }
  }
```

```
class SetValues extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        int status, net;

        SetValues(int status, int net) {
            this.status = status;
            this.net = net;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            update(status, net);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            weight.setText(decimalFormat.format(net));
            weight.invalidate();
            

        }
    }
```

> I Can't update weight textview. when i navigate to previous activity then coming to this activity and open the dialog fragment that time only this issue happening.
>
> Very first time working fine

Comment: Your question isn't clear

Comment: try runOnUIThread, i  think it will be work

Comment: first check whether onPostExecute() gets executes or not. as you are coming back to this activity from previous activity, might be AsyncTask has terminated being executing

Comment: @Arwy Shelke yes, onPostExecute() executes. when i am trying runOnUIThread same this happening

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh tried bro.. same thing happening

Comment: then debug what you have done here -> 1)weight.setText(decimalFormat.format(net));  &
2) weight.invalidate();     What weight.invalidate(); does it mean ??

Comment: @ArwyShelke Already done bro. The line is reached, but not working. very first time working fine. when i was finish the current activity and come to the same activity on the dialogFragment, it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
weight.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
     weight.setText(decimalFormat.format(net));
  }
 });
```

OR

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override 
      public void run() { 
        weight.setText(decimalFormat.format(net));
    });
```

Comment: I started with runOnUiThread. It was not worked.. that's what i tried with AsyncTask. this issue second time coming means may be i am missing something else

Comment: check once what  decimalFormat.format(net) returns .